# Remember information about the previous page?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape Bet365 for it's live soccer odds. I'm iterating over a list of live matches available. For each match I need to click on the match and I'll be directed to some new content where I have all the detailed oddsinfo. From here it crashes when I go back to keep on my iterating.

It throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christian/Google Drev/Data Science/Bet365/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    getScoreH = game.find_element_by_css_selector(scoreH).text
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 430, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 654, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.0 x86_64)
```

The error comes from the last code in my main.py:

```
# HERE IT BREAKS!: 

# Redirects to a games detailed odds page 
game.find_element_by_css_selector(oddsBtn).click() 
time.sleep(5)

# Go back and keep choose the click the next games details.
obj.find_element(overview).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Below is my program. But as I said, the problem comes from the main.py's last few lines of code where I need to go back to an iteration. It seems like it doesn't remember where I left off.

cls_scraper.py:

```
"""
    Class to find element(s) by css selector
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import platform
import time
import os


class Scraper():
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def wait(self, element):
        return WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, element)))

    def element_exist_css(self, element):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(element)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('Element doesnt exist')
            return False
        return True

    def element_css(self, element):

        try:
            time.sleep(2)
            return WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                                                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, element)))
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            print("XB: StaleElementReferenceException")
        except WebDriverException:
            print("XB: WebDriverException")

    def find_elements(self, element):

        time.sleep(2)
        return self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(element)

    def find_element(self, element):

        time.sleep(2)
        return self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(element)
```

str_elements.py:

```
"""
    String library to have relevant css selector elements in one place.
"""

""" BET 365 - Overview-page """

# Enter the page
enterPage   = '#TopPromotionMainArea'

# Page with live odds
inPlay      = 'body > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.hm-HeaderModule_Primary > div.hm-BigButtons > nav > a:nth-child(2)'

# Element containing relevent games and info about time, score etc, se below.
games       = 'div.ipo-FixtureRenderer.ipo-Competition_Container > div'
# For each game in games, these elements can be found:
teamH       = 'div.ipo-TeamStack > div:nth-child(1)'
teamA       = 'div.ipo-TeamStack > div:nth-child(2)'
scoreH      = 'div.ipo-TeamPoints_TeamScore.ipo-TeamPoints_TeamScore-teamone'
scoreA      = 'div.ipo-TeamPoints_TeamScore.ipo-TeamPoints_TeamScore-teamtwo'
gameTime    = 'div.ipo-InPlayTimer'

# The redirection in order to get all kinds of odds from a match
# Main overview-page only show a part of it.
oddsBtn     = 'div.ipo-FixtureEventCountButton_EventCountWrapper'

# The overview tab to see all the live games
overview    = 'div.ip-ControlBar > span.ip-ControlBar_ButtonBar > div:nth-child(1)'

# Choose english language             
langTab     = 'body > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.hm-HeaderModule_Secondary > div.hm-HeaderModule_Menus > div.hm-LanguageDropDownSelections.hm-DropDownSelections > a'
pickEng     = 'body > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.hm-HeaderModule_Secondary > div.hm-HeaderModule_Menus > div.hm-LanguageDropDownSelections.hm-DropDownSelections.hm-DropDownSelections_Selected > div > div > a:nth-child(1)'

# Get a better overview
allMarkets  = 'body > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.wc-PageView > div.wc-PageView_Main.wc-InPlayPage_MainContainer > div > div > div.ipo-OverViewView > div > div > div > div.ipo-OverViewDetail > div.ipo-OverViewDetail_Container.ipo-Classification > div.ipo-ClassificationHeader_Header.ipo-ClassificationHeader_Header-1.ipo-ClassificationHeader_Header-lightgreenborder.ipo-ClassificationHeader_Header-moremarkets > div.ipo-ClassificationHeader_MarketsButtonOuterWrapper > div > div.ipo-ClassificationHeader_MarketsButton.ipo-ClassificationHeader_MarketsButton-transparent'

""" BET 365 - Odds-page """
# Collect all the odds from the redirection page.
```

main.py:

```
""" Run program from here """
from str_elements import *
from cls_scraper  import *
from browser.path import *
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Welcome \n")
    # Open website
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)
    driver.get('https://www.bet365.dk/#/HO/')

    """ Click relevant elements """
    print("Bet365: Pressing buttons ...")
    obj = Scraper(driver)
    obj.element_css(enterPage).click()  # Enters the bet365 main page
    obj.element_css(inPlay).click()     # Presses the in-play tab
    obj.element_css(langTab).click()    # Choose languages
    obj.element_css(pickEng).click()    # Choose english
    obj.element_css(overview).click()   # Shows all live games
    obj.element_css(allMarkets).click() # Better overview

    print("Bet365: Collecting game data ...")

    # All live games
    liveContainer = obj.find_elements(games)        # Contains a list of running games

    for game in liveContainer:

        getScoreH = game.find_element_by_css_selector(scoreH).text
        getScoreA = game.find_element_by_css_selector(scoreA).text
        getTeamH  = game.find_element_by_css_selector(teamH).text
        getTeamA  = game.find_element_by_css_selector(teamA).text
        getTime   = game.find_element_by_css_selector(gameTime).text

        print("Score:   ", getScoreH, "-", getScoreA)
        print("GameTime:", getTime)
        print("HomeTeam:", getTeamH)
        print("AwayTeam:", getTeamA)
        print("")

        ## HERE IT BREAKS!: 

        ## Redirects to a games detailed odds page 
        # game.find_element_by_css_selector(oddsBtn).click() 
        # time.sleep(5)

        ## Go back and keep choose the click the next games details.
        # obj.find_element(overview).click()
        # time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: selenium won't remember previous page state, so you have 2 options: 1 - get your program to remember which element it processed, so each time it navigates back to previous page and selects the next link. 2 - inject (using JS) a target for link to be in new window. That way opening link won't affect original page, so you can open the link, switch to second window, process the link, switch back, etc

Comment: also... get rid of `time.sleep(2)` - you already have a proper `WebDriverWait`, so make a good use of it. Define it globally: `wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)` and then instead of every `find_element` where you have `sleep`, add `wait.until` and same condition as in `find-element`

Comment: Thanks Kiril S, I'll try to work with your options :-)